# i want to know how i can get the UUID of BLE device which is needed to connect IOS app to BLE device in android, same as like vice-versa?

Tags: ios-bluetooth, android-ble

Actually, I'm new in BLE, and In Android, if I am searching for available devices, so i got some Address, which is like, "8A:WS:YV:23:D7", and if i'm searching for the same device in IOS, then it gives some UUID like, "212C543B-9728-197D-B4F4-F4F74CABC963", like this, and both are used to connect our mobile app to BLE device, so my problem is i want to create a database, which is going to be used in both side, and i want to store the DB into server, when I'm uploading it through Android, it saves with Address, and if I'm opening that same profile from server in IOS, so it got Address instead of UUID, so that my device is not at all able to connect it. so i want to know how i can get the UUID of BLE device which is needed to connect IOS app to BLE device in android, same as like vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot get the mac address on iOS or the UUID on Android. Apple hides the mac address and your app won't pass the approval if you find a workaround (if there is any). The UUID used in iOS is generated based on the ble advertisement, every iOS device will generate a different UUID for the same peripheral. Btw new Android devices will randomise their mac address, so you cannot use the mac address as identifier anyway.

I suggest you provide your own identifier in the ble advertisement, so you can identify devices running your app. For example you add a service UUID to the advertisement, which would have two parts, a fixed one for identifying your app and a variable part identifying your device. Unfortunately it is not possible for an Android device to get the service UUID of an iOS device in background.

I hope this helps.